# You and X others like this

Tags: php, mysql

I am putting a system together and I would like to get the amount of rows of users that doesn't include the `session['id']` user so I can show the link a bit like facebooks.

Example: `You and x.. others likes this`

Obviously just using the standard num rows grabs all the records from the database but I'd like to exclude the session.

```
$likes = mysqli_query($mysqli, "
    SELECT feedback_streamid,feedback_userid,feedback_rating FROM streamdata_feedback 
        WHERE feedback_streamid=".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']." 
        AND feedback_rating=1 ORDER BY feedback_id LIMIT 10") 

        or die("SELECT Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));

$numRowslikes = mysqli_num_rows($likes);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($likes)) {
    $likesmemberid = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($row['feedback_userid']);
    $user1_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user2_id = $row['feedback_userid'];
    if ($user2_id == $_SESSION['id']) {
        echo '<div class="like_name"><b><a href="profile.php?username='.$likesmemberid['username'].'">You and</a> '.$numRowslikes.' Others likes this </b> ';
    } else {
    echo '<a title="'.$likesmemberid['fullname'].' Likes This" href="profile.php?username='.$likesmemberid['username'].'"> <img border=\'0\' src=\'../userimages/    cropped'.$row['feedback_userid'].'.jpg\' onerror="this.src=\'userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\'" width=\'20\' ></a> ';

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just fetch all the likes, `count($likes) - 1;` then `USER and $count likes this`..?

Comment: @Darren: And if _you_ didn't like it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Assuming the user does like the currrent feed.

Comment: @Darren: And what sane system would assume that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the early morning system.

Comment: Who's down voted, its a good question, of which I assume nobody as asked as I searched before hand.

Comment: If you do a separate query above without the NOT IN and put it into the same DIV it works perfectly. Cheers guys!
If anyone can come up with an answer in which it can be done all in one query and block please feel free to add an update.

Comment: @Dave No it's not a good question. It's way too specific and way too localised, and something you could do just by thinking about it. It's not a "how does this language work" sort of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could just change your query to exclude the current user's ID, then use num_rows() as normal.

```
WHERE feedback_userid NOT IN ('whatever_id_here')
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you for that Chris. I should of tried that because I thought about it.

Comment: -1: Then how do you know whether the current user liked the item?

Comment: It would have to be in a separate query just underneath.